# overlayFill for pieplot with image isn not working properly in coreplot iOS

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios6.1

I am filling the overlay of piePlot with an image instead of filling with gradient colors.

Here is the code :

```
piePlot.pieRadius       = radius;
piePlot.identifier      = @"1";
piePlot.startAngle      = 0.0;
piePlot.sliceDirection  = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;
piePlot.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
piePlot.labelOffset     = 5.0;
piePlot.overlayFill     = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pointerPie.png"].CGImage]];
piePlot.centerAnchor    = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

Here the problem is only some part of the overlay image I can see instead of full image.
If I fill the it with any other color its working fine.

what wrong I did here. Can anyone suggest me where and what I did wrong here?

Comment: Are you on a Retina device and/or simulator?

Comment: @EricSkroch: I am testing in simulator.

Comment: What simulator device? Is the simulated screen Retina (@2x) or not?

Comment: @EricSkroch: its Retina Simulated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `scale` of the image fill so that it is drawn correctly. You can do it when you create the `CPTImage`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pointerPie.png"];
piePlot.overlayFill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage
                                                                  scale:image.scale]];
```

Comment: I done the same as u suggested but Still it is with the same problem.

Comment: @MonishKumar Can you post a screenshot? My answer addresses a common problem with Core Plot images. I can't tell what else might be wrong from your description.